# EndpointNotFoundException - 404 - Hosting WCF Service over HTTPS in IIS through Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, iis

I'm developing a WCF service using transport security settings. When testing client proxy and calling service method I get following `EndpointNotFoundException`:

> There was no endpoint listening at `https://MyPC/AMTA.WebService/BroadcastInfoService.svc` that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>
> Inner exception:
>   The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

I'm hosting my service through visual studio.

`web.config` for service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
  <service name="AMTA.WebService.Broadcasts.BroadcastInfoService">
    <endpoint address="/BroadcastInfoService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="AMTA.WebService.Interface.Broadcasts.IBroadcastInfoService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TransportSecurity">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Config for client:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
          <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IBroadcastInfoService">
            <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
            </security>
          </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://MyPC/AMTA.WebService/BroadcastInfoService.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IBroadcastInfoService"
            contract="BroadcastInfoService.IBroadcastInfoService" name="WSHttpBinding_IBroadcastInfoService">
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I'm deploying using Web property page of the project to local IIS using this virtual directory:

```
https://MyPC:443/AMTA.WebService/
```

I can browse `https://MyPC:443/AMTA.WebService/BroadcastInfoService.svc` after hitting F5, which shows page with wsdl info. Though when I try to call methods on client proxy, endpoint not found exception is being thrown with following log details

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   The service '/AMTA.WebService/BroadcastInfoService.svc/' does not exist.
>   StackTrace
>   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)

Https and Http host headers are enabled for IIS and Https is tied to self-signed certificate.

Comment: Is 443 open between the host and client? Are the host and client on the same box? Try this: https: [no space] //127.0.0.1:443/AMTA.WebService/BroadcastInfoService.svc

Comment: Yes, everything is on the same machine.

Comment: So try Localhost or 127.0.0.1 and see if you get a different result.

Comment: What happens when you browse to the same address that you have in your client configuration? You said you browse to `https://MyPC:443/AMTA.WebService/BroadcastInfoService.svc` in the browser and it works, but your client config says `https://MyPC/AMTA.WebService/BroadcastInfoService.svc` which may not resolve to the same location depending on how your IIS/IIS Express/Visual Studio web site is configured. Also, what host name is the cert issued to? That may cause you some additional issues later if the cert is issued to `MyPC.Domain.com` or `localhost` and you're browsing to `MyPc`

Comment: I have regenerated service reference and got strange result in new client config: address="...AMTA.WebService/BroadcastInfoService.svc/BroadcastInfoService.svc"

Comment: Cert is issued to MyPC. I've tried different combinations in client config without luck. I've also looked into my wsdl and svc file is doubled in address - ...AMTA.WebService/BroadcastInfoService.svc/BroadcastInfoService.svc

Comment: No luck with Localhost or 127.0.0.1, either with or without port

Comment: Not sure what to suggest ... from the symptoms, it sounds like the client can't find the host, that's why I suggested using localhost or its IP equivalent.

Comment: When I look into my cert in IIS I get - "This CA Root Certificate is not trusted" - maybe this is the cause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The culprit was missing

> bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"

from endpoint element in web.config.

By the way you can meet security requirements by just using basicHttpsBinding, which is new to  .Net 4.5. This will lead to a more concise xml configs. Which are from the devil anyways.