# SQL Server database, wcf and WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, wcf

I have a sweet WinForm application (on my computer) and a SQL Server database (on server X). I'm using `SqlConnection` and everything works fine.

But not I want to change it and use WCF or other technologies to connect and switch information between my app and database.

I also have one more server to use as application server (Server Y).

I've started using WCF: created project, created installer.

Uploaded it on my Y server and installed it. Service started, also I've added Service Reference to my WinForm app, but the `ServiceClient` is not working properly.

When I call `ServiceClient`'s method it throws exception:

> An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:41272/service that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

As I guess my endpoint is blowing things up.

So I want you guys help me how to configure SQL endpoint.

Here is my WCF's `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime />
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="SampleSvcBehavior">
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="SampleSvcBehavior"  
                     name="FMG_WCF.FmgService">
                <endpoint name="SampleSvcBasicHttpEndPoint" 
                    address="" 
                    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                    contract="FMG_WCF.IFmgService" />
                <endpoint name="SampleSvcMexHttpEndPoint" 
                    address="mex" 
                    binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                    contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:41272/service" />
                    </baseAddresses>
               </host>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `localhost:41272` is not a remote machine.

Comment: thank you for response, Preston Guillot.
sure it's not. my question is how to configure endpoint for my server X

Comment: I believe you do not required the end points for the database server. you just need a connection string to connect with database from your WCF service.

Comment: You need your client config to actually use the address of the remote service, right now it's using `localhost:41272`.

Comment: yes yes yes. I have my connection string. and sure I can use SqlConnection same way.
but what about endpoint exception.
I can't call any ServiceClient methods. All of them throws that EndpointNotFoundException

Comment: Are you debugging locally? By default your WCF service will use IIS Express. You just have to be running it for the forms application to be able to talk to it. Try debugging the service. Once it's started, try communicating with it from the winforms app.

Comment: Thank you Scott. I'll try it now.

Answer (score 0):

This error is not related with SQL endpoint. In facts you do not need endpoints for connecting WCF to database. Here is your answer in another post.

[EndpointNotFoundException - 404 - Hosting WCF Service over HTTPS in IIS through Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187550/endpointnotfoundexception-404-hosting-wcf-service-over-https-in-iis-through)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, if the service has been modified from when you created it you can simply right click on the service reference and configure the service reference. In the popup you can change the Url to point to serverX and you service reference and config file will be automatically updated.

If no changes were made to the service, for example your binding type or security then simply updating the Url in the config file should be enough.